# zip contents of the folders

Tags: gradle

I want to zip the content of package folders.
How to do it in a `gradle` task?

I am trying to do like this

```
task publishAll << {
    new File('src/main/resources/com/domain/application/').eachDir() {
        dir -> processFolder(dir)
    }
}

def processFolder(dir) {
    println "prepare folder: " + dir
```

And it seems to return first-level subfolders fine. 
But how to zip that `dir` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom task with the `Zip` type and use `FileTree` to include all subfolder with it's contetnt into the zip-archive, like:

```
task publishAll(type: Zip){
    from fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/com/domain/application/')
}
```

If you want additionally print the file names, you can modify it to:

```
from fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/com/domain/application/').each {println it.name}
```

**Update:** to archive every folder in separate zip-file, you can use your solution to traverse over directories and add the `ant.zip` task, to pack them, like:

```
task publishAll << {
    new File('src/main/resources/com/domain/application/').eachDir {
        ant.zip(destfile: it.name+'.zip', basedir: it.path){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to `zip` every folder into separate file. Zipping is just a subprocess inside task

Comment: @user1432980 updated an answer. now it makes an archive for every 1st level folder within the target directory